# Flex 4 Group showEffect/hideEffect

Tags: apache-flex, effects

I have a Group that I want to do a wipe effect when it shows and hides.

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    <s:Wipe id="wipeUp" direction="up" duration="2000"/>
    <s:Wipe id="wipeDown" direction="down" duration="2000" startDelay="2000"/>
</fx:Declarations>

<s:Group 
    id="zoomPopup"
    top="-290"
    right="15"
    width="30"
    height="300"
    visible="false" 
    showEffect="{wipeUp}" hideEffect="{wipeDown}">
```

The group is being hidden and shown on change of the group's visibility, but the effect doesn't do anything.  When I set the visibility to false, it takes 4 secs for it to hide (delay+duration), but again, no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Effect triggers are not officially supported in spark in the current release.  See this thread for more details: [Spark effects: why is procedural code preferred over triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420282/spark-effects-why-is-procedural-code-preferred-over-triggers/4425071#4425071)

Comment: I dont find this to be true.  In the code above I stated that effect would get triggered but it would not actually wipe.  So, when the hideEffect was triggered, it would wait 4 secs (duration+startDelay) before the group would no longer be visible.

Comment: It's not officially supported so the behavior will be unknown.  In some cases it will work, in some cases it wont, in other cases it might do weird things.  You could try setting Wipe.target=zoomPopUp and it might work.