# How can I add effects to the show/hide of a spark control?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, effects, flex-spark

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flex 4 Group showEffect/hideEffect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567172/flex-4-group-showeffect-hideeffect)

I have an existing flex application that uses databinding to show/hide certain elements. It looks a little like this:

```
<namespace:CustomComponent visible="{modelObject.showCustomComponent}" />
```

To spruce it up a little bit, I went in and did this:

```
<s:Move id="ccRollIn" target="{cc}" xFrom="-400" xTo="50" />
...
<namespace:CustomComponent id="cc" visible="{modelObject.showCustomComponent}" show="ccRollIn.play()" hide="ccRollIn.play(null, true)" />
```

The problem with this is that while the show event plays perfectly, the item disappears from view before the hide effect has a chance to play. Is there a simple way to handle adding animations to this workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `showEffect` and `hideEffect` as [in documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html) or [in this sample](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2009/06/30/creating-a-show-effect-on-a-spark-panel-container-in-flex-4/).

Answer (score 0):

Change the component line to

```
<ns:Component showEffect="{move1}" hideEffect="{move2}" />
```

and in the Declarations, add this:

```
<s:Move id="move1" xFrom="-400" xTo="50" />
<s:Move id="move2" xTo="-400" xFrom="50" />
```