# Flex 4 hideEffect transition bug

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, effects, transition

I'm trying to create a slide effect. Everything works fine except when the hideEffect animation is shown for the first time. The content does not become invisible when crossing the TabNavigator's border, which looks really ugly in my current project.

The following simple example demonstrates the problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                  xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                  xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                  backgroundColor="0xDDDDDD">

     <fx:Declarations>
          <s:Move id="hideEffect" xTo="700" />
     </fx:Declarations>

     <mx:TabNavigator width="500" height="300" x="100" y="0">

          <s:NavigatorContent label="ONE" hideEffect="{hideEffect}">
               <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0xFF0000" height="100" width="100"/>
          </s:NavigatorContent>

          <s:NavigatorContent label="TWO" hideEffect="{hideEffect}">
               <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0xFF0000" height="100" width="100"/>
          </s:NavigatorContent>

          <s:NavigatorContent label="THREE" hideEffect="{hideEffect}">
               <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0xFF0000" height="100" width="100"/>
          </s:NavigatorContent>

          <s:NavigatorContent label="FOUR" hideEffect="{hideEffect}">
               <s:BorderContainer backgroundColor="0xFF0000" height="100" width="100"/>
          </s:NavigatorContent>

     </mx:TabNavigator>

</s:Application>
```

Screenshot: [hideEffectBug](http://tinyurl.com/hideeffectbug)

Any ideas how to fix this bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Effect triggers like hideEffect are not officially supported in spark.  See this thread for more information: [Spark effects: why is procedural code preferred over triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420282/spark-effects-why-is-procedural-code-preferred-over-triggers/4425071#4425071)

Please vote for http://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/SDK-19743 if you would like to see this implemented in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the information. Using <mx:Move> instead of <s:Move> does the trick.