# Problem getting in Flex Effects: Migration from Flex3 to Flex4

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I am using Flex4. I want to get some animation effects in my project.

I used `<s:Wipe>` but this doesn't work, however with same type of code, `<mx:WipeLeft>` worked.
However I dont want to use `<mx>` code, if its more-generic spark code is available in Flex4.

My both type of codes are:

MX Code- (working code)

```
<mx:WipeLeft id="wLeft" duration="1500" target="{imgSinglePage}"/>
```

Spark code- (Not working)

```
<s:Wipe id="wLeft" duration="1500" direction="left" target="{imgSinglePage}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your declaration of the effects themselves that is causing your problem.  Since you didn't include your actual invocation code, I can only guess that you are attempting to use an effects trigger (eg. `rollOverEffect="wLeft"`) to execute the Spark effect.

The Spark effects can only be invoked by calling their `play()` method.  So in your case, you would use

`... rollOver="wLeft.end();wLeft.play();" ...`

on the relevant component.

Here's the [official Adobe description](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingSDK/WSa122979b461972566d16c457125b7d3d121-7ff8.html#WSa122979b461972565dfb4c0c125b7e73f11-8000).

And here's a [discussion on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4420282/spark-effects-why-is-procedural-code-preferred-over-triggers) of the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Effects can work with transitions using Flex 4's state system, or can be triggered by events in components.

Specified in a declarative way:

```
    <!--- Fade effects for showing / hiding elements -->
    <fx:Declarations>
        <s:Parallel id="fadeInEffect">
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="0"
                    alphaTo="1" />
        </s:Parallel>
        <s:Parallel id="fadeOutEffect">
            <s:Fade alphaFrom="1"
                    alphaTo="0" />
        </s:Parallel>
    </fx:Declarations>


    <!-- Image -->
    <s:Image showEffect="{fadeInEffect}"
             hideEffect="{fadeOutEffect}" />
```

If this does not answer your question, please provide code that uses the effect you have referenced.